# Why does the Stack Exchange Android app sort by reputation on per-site metas?

Tags: support, android-app

On the mobile and desktop sites, users on per-site metas are sorted by **Participation**, **Creation date** and **Name** but on the Andriod app they are sorted by **Reputation**, **Creation date** and **Name**.

Why does the Android app sort by reputation instead of participation?

Comment: Guess the API simply does not expose that detail, so the app developers use what the API can give.